# Complex SVG clip-path responsive

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to take a complex path shape and apply it as a clip-path mask in css, but I can't figure out how to get the clip mask to "fill" the parent container. 
Rather it just gets cut off or doesn't expand to fill the available space.

If I add `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` it doesn't appear at all.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 720 720">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="map">
      <path d="M568.421 326.842L511.579 270v37.895h-18.947v-18.948h-56.843v37.895l18.948 37.894v18.948h-18.948l37.896 56.842h-37.896l-18.947-18.948v-18.947h-37.895L360 383.684h-18.947l-18.948-37.894v-37.895L360 270l37.895-37.895-18.948-37.895H360v18.948l-18.947-18.948h-18.948v37.895h-37.894l-56.843-18.947-37.894-56.842h-56.842l-18.947-18.948-75.79 75.79v37.895h18.947v75.789L37.895 345.79l5.532 48.163 32.362 46.573 113.685 37.895 94.737 18.947h94.736v-18.947h37.895l18.947 37.895h18.948v56.842l56.842-37.894v-37.896h37.895l18.947-37.894v-37.896l56.842-37.894V345.79l-18.948-18.948z"/><path d="M246.315 194.21h56.843v-18.947l-18.947-37.895h-18.948v37.895h-18.948zM227.368 137.368h18.947v-18.947h-37.894V156.316h18.947zM341.053 175.263h56.842l37.894 37.895-18.947 18.947V270h75.79v-18.947h-37.895v-18.948h37.895V194.21h-37.895l-56.842-56.842h-56.842zM265.263 99.474h18.948v18.947h-18.948zM284.211 61.579h18.947v18.948h-18.947zM303.158 108.947h18.947v18.947h-18.947zM341.053 99.474h37.895v18.947h-37.895zM227.368 80.526h18.947v18.947h-18.947zM378.947 80.526V4.737H360l-37.895 37.894v18.948l18.948 18.947zM587.368 440.526h37.895v37.895h-37.895zM663.158 364.736V345.79h-18.947V402.631l56.842-18.947v-18.948zM378.947 270h18.947v18.947h-18.947zM644.211 421.578h18.947v18.948h-18.947zM644.211 459.474h18.947v18.947h-18.947z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/picard102/pen/aEwJzR

Comment: When you convert the units you need to convert the values too. Otherwise it's like converting the units from millimetres to kilometres and expecting the drawing to be the same scale.

Comment: @RobertLongson not sure what you mean. The units are straight out of Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Those are userSpaceOnUse units, you said changing the units to objectBoundingBox doesn't work. When you change the units you must change the values to be appropriate for those units.

Comment: @RobertLongson so I need to convert the value in path to some other value somehow?

Comment: objectBoundingBox units are in the range 0..1 scale as required.

Comment: I don't see any tools that will do that conversion without mangling the svg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Robert said, when you specify `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, the coordinates in the clip path definition are supposed to be between `0,0` (the top left) and `1,1` (the bottom right).

Your paths are about 700x575, so your path is about 600 to 700 times too big.

The simplest solution is to add a `transform` attribute to your `<clipPath>` that scales the coordinates down to the correct range.

```
<clipPath id="map" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.00143, 0.00174)">
```

- 1/700 ~= 0.00143
- 1/575 ~= 0.00174

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyvZOM

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the mask not change aspect ratio?

Comment: If you use `objectBoundingBox` then x will scale to the width of the original object, and y will scale to the height. So the only way to avoid the aspect ratio changing is to make the aspect ratios of the clipPath and the original object the same.